# get <TD> Value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Iam trying to get td values in tr with id=jf and push there values into an array but when to get this array it just store the first td valuse and others array elements are Undefined

```
<table id="customers" >
            <tr id="jf">
            <td>Students Name</td>
            <td>Students SSN</td>
            <td>Class</td>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>third</td>
            <td>Final</td>
            </tr>
</table>
<button id='addr' onclick='addnewr()'> Add </button>
<script>
var count_td_def=document.getElementById("jf").cells;
function insertdata()
{
    var tdvs=[];

    for(var j=0;j<count_td_def.length;j++)
    {

        var tdv=document.getElementById("jf").cells[j].innerHTML;
        tdvs.push(tdv[j]);
        alert(tdvs[j])
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: TDs don't have value.

Comment: @Teemu i mean to get what's inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementById` to get the row and `querySelectorAll('td')` to get the `td`. Then use `map` to create an array of the text

```js
function insertdata() {
  var tdv = [...document.getElementById("jf").querySelectorAll('td')].map((item) => {
    return item.innerHTML
  })

  console.log(tdv)
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr id="jf">
    <td>Students Name</td>
    <td>Students SSN</td>
    <td>Class</td>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>third</td>
    <td>Final</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id='addr' onclick='insertdata()'> Add </button>
```